# tcp/ip client server not working over internet

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm going to setup a small client/server server in TCP/IP mode, I use VS2010,C# to develop my apps, I've googled a lot and could find some source codes, but none of them work in internet, I can get some answers in my own local system, i.e. I run my server, then listen for my own localhost (127.0.0.1) then send some data (for example using telnet), it works fine but when I do the same over internet I get nothing! I want to use port 80, as I want to send/receive http data, I have tested several source codes, here is the last code I have used (and it works on localhost with telnet)

//server code:

```
form_load()
    IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 80);

            // Bind the socket to the end point
            listenSocket.Bind(ipEndpoint);

            // Start listening, only allow 1 connection to queue at the same time
            listenSocket.Listen(1);
            listenSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), listenSocket);
            Console.WriteLine("Server is waiting on socket {0}", listenSocket.LocalEndPoint);

            // Start being important while the world rotates
            while (true)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Busy Waiting....");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

        public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AsyncCall)
    {
         System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        Byte[] message = encoding.GetBytes("I am a little busy, come back later!");

        Socket listener = (Socket)AsyncCall.AsyncState;
        Socket client = listener.EndAccept(AsyncCall);

        Console.WriteLine("Received Connection from {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint);
        client.Send(message);

        Console.WriteLine("Ending the connection");
        client.Close();
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), listener);
    }
```

send data (client), of course I haven't used this code, is it right?

```
        public static string SendData()
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IP, 80);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

        //if statement evalutes to see if the user has selected to update the server
        //" " = update server
        //"" = do not update the server
        //if (updateData.Equals(""))
        //{
        //    space = "";
        //}
        //else if (!updateData.Equals(""))
        //{
        //    space = " ";
        //}
        //Refrences stream writer, username variable passed in from GUI
        //space variable provides update function: "" = dont update. " " = update database.
        sw.WriteLine("h");
        sw.Flush();
        //data send back from the server assigned to string variable 
        //string recieved = sr.ReadLine();
        return "";

    }
```

I'm going to have the server code in my Server (winserver 2008R2) but currently test it in normal PCs, what am I doing wrong? I want to send some http packet from a random system (with a random IP) to my server (which I know its IP), what should I do? is it possible with tcp/ip or I should do something else?
is it related to static IP? should I certainly have static IP? my web server has a static IP but my clients do not, is it a problem?
I think I have some problem in defining ports and IPs, how should I set them? my server has a specific IP, but I don't know IP of my clients, would you please explain it to me step by step?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most common problems in this scenario:

1. Ensure your server's router is using [port forwarding](http://portforward.com/) to forward HTTP requests from the router to the server.
2. Ensure you are connecting to the server's [public IP address](http://www.whatismyip.org/), not its local network address.

Comment: thanks but how can I know about server router? can I use my own PC as a server for my testing? in this way how can I test router? what do you mean by server public IP address? how can I find it?

Comment: thanks but I cannot find a clear answer, is there a good tutorial/sample displaying the things work in web?